# Issues adding python to atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am not sure how to use python in atom.  Any assitance is welcome!  This is the error when i try to run my script!

Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

```
ENV PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\; 
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Syste 
m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA 
Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management 
Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\; 
C:\WINDOWS\system32;    
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;   
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd; 
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\bin;
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin; 
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Users\dalef\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApp;   
C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin; 

Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: By default, Atom does not run code. It would be helpful to know which package you use to run code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like when you installed python you might not have checked the box to install an environment variable. This means you can uninstall python and recheck the box if python 3.5 or greater. Similarly if you can't do that then it means manually go into your System properties and add a python path go to environment variables and add the python path.

If you still aren't sure I would recommend uninstalling python or adding it to your path( "Edit the System Environment Variables" -> Click Environment Variables -> then in the path section edit the path to include the python path) Once this is done I would reccomend in atom to go to  Packages-> Command Palette-> Toggle. Once there search View install packages and themes. Once in their type and install Script and install it. Now type ctrl+shift+b and you should be able to run the program